# How can I use sed to generate a list of files to be deleted via rm?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a compute cluster that takes input files and generates two output files from `stdout` and `stderr` and the error file is empty if thing ran correctly. Since we do *a lot* of runs in parallel, I just want to maintain the inputs and logs when there is an error. This breaks down to the following tasks:

1. Find all of the empty error logs.
2. Find the prefix that corresponds to a given batch.
3. Delete all of the files related to that batch.

A batch of files looks like the following:

```
25584-0.8-0.170-bfa.yml
25584-0.8-0.175-bfa.pbs
25584-0.8-0.175-bfa.pbs.e20693449
25584-0.8-0.175-bfa.pbs.o20693449
```

So far I've sorted out how to find the files:

```
find . -name '*.pbs.e*' -size 0
```

and how to extract the generic prefix that applies to all of the files:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\.pbs.e.*/\1.*/'
```

so piping all of these together I would expect the following to delete all of the files associated with compute jobs that had no errors:

```
find . -name '*.pbs.e*' -size 0 | sed 's/\(.*\)\.pbs.e.*/\1.*/' | xargs -d '\n' rm
```

However the output I get for all matching cases is the following:

```
rm: cannot remove `./25584-0.8-0.170-bfa.*': No such file or directory
```

Manually typing out the command (e.g., `rm 25584-0.8-0.170-bfa.*`) works a expected and it appears that `sed` appends a `\n` to the output which means the `| xargs rm` or `| xargs -d '\n' rm` pipes are generating the error.

How can I format the output from `sed` (or similar tool) so that the matching files will be deleted?

Comment: can you provide a test case ? I am using bash in red-hat version 4.2.46 and I have no such issue. I can delete all files in one directory after retrieving the names using sed and passing the output to xargs

Comment: `piping to` piping what? `How can I format the output from sed (or similar tool) so that the matching files will be deleted?` You can't, because it's unrelated to `sed`. No, `sed` can't do [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html), that is something your shell does _before_ running `rm foo*`.

Comment: @rjzii , can you provide a sample of list of files that match the pattern you are looking for ? I did a test using sample files, applying sed a couple of times,and running xargs to the result of sed. I would like to test it with your real scenario of file names

Comment: @RobertoHernandez Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get

```
rm: cannot remove './25584-0.8-0.170-bfa.*': No such file or directory
```

is that this command was executed:

```
rm "./25584-0.8-0.170-bfa.*"
```

where the argument is a string containing a star and not a glob expression. A glob needs to be expanded by a shell and given to the command as arguments.

---

For this directory

```
-rw-r--r--  1 t users    0 Jul 20 22:10 25584-0.8-0.175-bfa.pbs
-rw-r--r--  1 t users    0 Jul 20 22:10 25584-0.8-0.175-bfa.pbs.e20693449
-rw-r--r--  1 t users    0 Jul 20 22:10 25584-0.8-0.175-bfa.pbs.o20693449
-rw-r--r--  1 t users    0 Jul 20 22:10 25584-0.8-0.176-bfa.pbs
-rw-r--r--  1 t users    0 Jul 20 22:10 25584-0.8-0.176-bfa.pbs.e20693449
-rw-r--r--  1 t users    0 Jul 20 22:10 25584-0.8-0.176-bfa.pbs.o20693449
```

Here we print two strings:

```
> find . -name '*.pbs.e*' -size 0 | sed 's/\(.*\)\.pbs.e.*/\1.*/' |\
xargs -I@ echo @

./25584-0.8-0.175-bfa.*
./25584-0.8-0.176-bfa.*
```

Here we call a shell which is expanding the arguments before giving them to the command:

```
> find . -name '*.pbs.e*' -size 0 | sed 's/\(.*\)\.pbs.e.*/\1.*/' |\
xargs -I@ bash -c "echo @"

./25584-0.8-0.175-bfa.pbs ./25584-0.8-0.175-bfa.pbs.e20693449 ./25584-0.8-0.175-bfa.pbs.o20693449
./25584-0.8-0.176-bfa.pbs ./25584-0.8-0.176-bfa.pbs.e20693449 ./25584-0.8-0.176-bfa.pbs.o20693449
```

which is what you need, so your command could be modified to:

```
find . -name '*.pbs.e*' -size 0 | sed 's/\(.*\)\.pbs.e.*/\1.*/' | xargs -I@ bash -c "rm -- @"
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that there is more than one way of doing this, but since a one liner isn't needed the issues with `sed` can be bypassed by just using a loop:

```
for item in `find . -name '*.pbs.e*' -size 0 | sed 's/\(.*\)\.pbs.e.*/\1.*/'`; do
  rm $item
done
```

Answer (score 0):

the asterisk * is taken as literal character and not expected filename expansion. you can pass your `sed` to another `find` which takes literal * in `-name` pattern without evaluating it

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.pbs.e*' -size 0 | sed 's,^\./\(.*\)\.pbs\.e.*,\1.*,' | xargs -n1 -I{} find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '{}' -print -delete
```

to make the sed a little more safe you can run it on full path, only culprit you must extra escape meta characters in path name

```
# search dir
dir=.
dir=$(realpath "$dir")

# that should escape meta-characters in non-trivial dir name
# stackoverflow.com/q/15783701
printf -v dirstr '%q' "$dir"

# $dirstr is used for sed but can replaced with $dir for simple dir name
find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.pbs.e*' -size 0 | sed "s,^$dirstr/\(.*\)\.pbs\.e.*,\1.*," | xargs -n1 -I{} find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name {} -print -delete
```

should work with whitespace and other non-trivial file names (except for `\n`)

Comment: just removed leading `./` from file name and replaced *rm* with *find -delete* in your origin code, i think that is closest you can get  ;)